# Opening a .exe with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, on-screen-keyboard

Im trying to get silverlight to open the OnscreenKeyboard. I wrote a code but it is throwing a System.InvalidOperationException.

```
 try
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Eval("var myshell = new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.shell' ); myshell.run( '" + OSK + "' );");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Items.Add(ex.ToString());
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being blocked by the security built in to IE.  Internet Explorer will only allow a few trusted COM objects to be constructed with `ActiveXObject`.  Could you imagine the havoc that could be wrought if a website had the permission to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of a security problem but is there no way to call the osk ? I know that Silverlight is a WebApplication and should not run any .exe but I need it for my touchscreen Application with textboxes.

Comment: @knut: Take a look at this: http://www.orktane.com/Blog/post/2009/11/09/Virtual-Input-Keyboard-Behaviours-for-Silverlight.aspx